# Convert Text to Dict [repetitive key in textline]

Tags: python, dictionary

I have sample text file as below

```
asy1 10.20.0.1
byt 192.1.10.100
byt 192.1.10.101
byt 192.1.10.102
hps 10.30.1.50
hps 10.30.1.53
hps 10.30.1.54
hps 10.30.1.55
hps 10.30.1.56
zte 10.100.1.1
zte 10.100.1.2
```

When i run script below

```
mydict = {}
with open('devices.txt', 'r') as file:
   for line in file:
      name, ip = line.split()
      mydict[name] = ip.strip()
print(mydict)
```

It not return all the line/content as per text file.

```
{'hps': '10.30.1.56', 'zte': '10.100.1.2', 'byt': '192.1.10.102', 'asy1': '10.20.0.1'}
```

I miss something here...Please advise me. Thanks

Comment: @DanielMesejo A dictionary can have multiple keys. They just have to have distinct hash values.

Answer (score 2):

In a dictionary the key must be uniques, when you do:

```
mydict[name] = ip.strip()
```

you overwrite the value, instead of having a single value for a key you could store a list of values, by doing this:

```
mydict = {}
with open('devices.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        name, ip = line.split()
        if name not in mydict:
            mydict[name] = []
        mydict[name].append(ip.strip())
print(mydict)
```

**Output**

```
{'asy1': ['10.20.0.1'], 'byt': ['192.1.10.100', '192.1.10.101', '192.1.10.102'], 'hps': ['10.30.1.50', '10.30.1.53', '10.30.1.54', '10.30.1.55', '10.30.1.56'], 'zte': ['10.100.1.1', '10.100.1.2']}
```

A second alternative would be to use [setdefault](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) instead:

```
mydict.setdefault(name, []).append(ip.strip())
```

A third option would be to use a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict). If the values are unique consider using a [set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html).

Comment: Noted and thanks, this also a good solution ... I need to test solutions given. Thanks for your response and help

Answer (score 0):

Many of those names are the same, but a `dict` can only have one value for a given key - if you try to add an IP to the dictionary with key `hps`, but there's already one in there, it will be overwritten. Maybe use a `list` instead?

Comment: My mistake...Thanks ....  I plan to create function of each key group (function for hps, zte, byt and so on) and execute specific process in it. Thus, the key name will differentiate which function and which process to execute.